# Get Discount Price Based on Promo Code

Tags: coupon-codes

I have a coupon code which is issued when subscribing to our newsletter. I'd like to show on the product page the discounted price with promo code applied:

Get this price for £23.45 by joining our newsletter!

The £23.45 is the price calculated once the promo code has been applied in the checkout.

Comment: This is not possible unless you do some hard coding. The cart rules work only in the context of a quote. There are a number of factors that can make a rule valid or not. In your case you don't have a quote object that you can use to process the rules.